# Magento Cloud - Error 503 first byte timeout during customer login

Tags: magento2, varnish, magento2-cloud, fastly

I'm facing a cache issue that wasn't there before, my **Adobe Commerce Cloud 2.4.5 + Fastly** is showing this error message below when I'm trying to log in via customer account or perform some actions in the admin panel.

[image: Magento 2 Cloud Error 503 first byte timeout]

How could I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by Fastly limits. Try to increase your `memory_limit` and `max_execution_time` in your **php.ini** and **pub/.user.ini** files.

Then run the command `composer update fastly/magento2`, to make sure you have the latest version of it. To complete the limits increasing, navigate to **admin -> stores -> configuration -> Advance -> System -> Full Page Cache**, set Admin path timeout to 600, and click on **"Upload VCL to Fastly"**, this will increase the first-byte timeout in Fastly (600 is the max).

[image: Magento 2 - Fastly Admin path timeout to 600]